# How does linq determine value changes?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

If the value of a field is not actually changed but reassigned the same value, will that reassignment be marked for update when submitting to database?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, simply setting the property marks it as dirty.

Comment: so how would you map doman objects to linq entities withot making them dirty every time?

Comment: Check the values before you set them, or use the LINQ objects as your domain objects.